# Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES) sending mails into spam

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon Simple Email Service (AWS SES) for sending email notification to the user.

When user enter his/her email correctly like abcd@gmail.com
mails are received into the inbox of the user

But when use enter email like abcd+1234@gmail.com

that time user get emails into the spam box of abcd@gmail.com account.

What could be the root cause of this or any solution for handling this type of situation.

Thanks

Comment: [Please Read this (this was already discuss in details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174584/amazon-ses-mails-as-spams)